# neo4j query extremly slow

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient, nosql

I want to create a graph using the neo4jclient ,  I have a dictionary that hold 2 kinds of object ( documents ,list) ,

```
Dictionary<Document, List<Concept>>
```

as you can see ,each document hold a list of concept ,a relationship must be between them (document)<-[:IN]-(concept)

```
 public void LoadNode(Dictionary<Document, List<Concept>> dictionary, GraphClient _client)
{
    var d = dictionary.ToList();
    var t = dictionary.Values;

    string merge1 = string.Format
           ("MERGE (source:{0} {{ {1}:row.Key.Id_Doc }})", "Document", "Name");
    string strForEachDoc = " FOREACH( concept in row.Value | ";
    string merge2 = string.Format
            ("MERGE (target:{0} {{ {1} : concept.Name }})", "Concept", "Name");
    string merge3 = string.Format
            (" MERGE (source)-[ r:{0} ]->(target)", "Exist");
     {_client.Cypher
           .WithParam("coll", d)
           .ForEach("(row in {coll} | " +
                merge1 + " " +
                strForEachDoc + " " +
                merge2 + " " +
                merge3 + "))")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }

}
```

it takes times and Visual studio ran into a bizarre error

> "Une exception de première chance de type 'System.AggregateException'
>   s'est produite dans mscorlib.dll"

Comment: An AggregateException means one or more exceptions occurred, which were then bundled up. You need to look at the InnerExceptions property to see what they were.

Comment: the **InnerExceptions**  Have:
[System.Exception{System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException}]:{"Une tâche a été annulée."}

*Message:Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites.
*Source :mscorlib

Comment: Can you translate to english the exception? It looks like to me there is a timeout exception. Task cancelled usually indicates there was a HTTP timeout.